# Is PCIe speed compatible with that of PCI

Tags: linux, speed, pci

If I go in for a PCIe to PCI adaptor, will I be constrained by speed. 
PCIe provides a faster interface than PCI. How can I make them speed compatible

Answer (score 0):

- [Conventional PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) (32-bit 33MHz) can transfer 133 MB/s.
- [PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) can transfer at least (for an x1 slot in PCI-E v1.x) 250 MB/s, and as much as 31.51 GB/s (for an x16 slot in PCI-E v4.0)

Comment: In short, with any PCI-> PCIe conversion or vice versa, your PCI device/interface will be the bottleneck